# Applescript - Getting a section of a POSIX path and creating a folder with that name

Tags: applescript

I have some files in a work folder that contains jobnames_jobnumber /work/jobnameA_001/outbox/filename.mp4, /work/jobnameB_002/outbox/flamename.mp4 e.t.c

I would like to have an applescript get the full POSIX path and extract just the jobnameA_001 part of the path then create a new folder with jobnames_jobnumber_date

Please note the jobnames are client names so they are not fixed length.

Please also note I am a complete newbie and am not sure what to research to find the answers. But i'll try.

Thank you kindly,

Comment: Here's some AppleScript documentation that may help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000156i and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html for more information about the `do shell script` command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that does what you want:

```applescript
# Extract all <jobName>_<jobNumber> tokens from matching paths.
set jobNamesWithNumbers to paragraphs of ¬
  (do shell script "for p in /work/*/outbox/*.mp4; do echo \"$p\"; done | 
                    awk -F/ '{ print $2 }'")

# Get the date in format YYYY-MM-DD, e.g., "2014-04-13".
set dateString to do shell script "date +'%Y-%m-%d'"

# Specify the target folder in which to create the new folders:
set targetFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop)

# Build the absolute paths of the folders to create.
set quotedFolderPathList to ""
repeat with itm in jobNamesWithNumbers
    set folderPath to (targetFolder & "/" & itm & "_" & dateString)
    set quotedFolderPathList to quotedFolderPathList & " " & ¬
                                  quoted form of folderPath
end repeat

# Finally, create the new folders.
do shell script "mkdir -p" & quotedFolderPathList
```

Note that this relies heavily on using shell (`bash`) commands invoked with `do shell script`, which makes for much shorter code.

This comes at the cost of having to understand *two* languages, however.
Given AppleScript's limitations, it's worth making this learning investment in the long run.